# Legend text cuts off using latex2exp in R plot

Tags: r, legend, latex2exp

The text in my legend cuts off using `library(latex2exp)` in a legend.

```
library(stats)
library(evd)
library(dgumbel)
library(latex2exp)

x=seq(-5,10,length.out=1001)

fgumb=dgumbel(x,location=0,scale=1)
ffrech=dfrechet(x,loc=0,scale=1,shape=1)
fweib=dweibull(x,shape=2,scale=1)

maxes=max(fgumb,ffrech,fweib)

plot(x,fgumb,type='l',lwd=2,col='blue',ylim=c(0,maxes),
     ylab="f(x)")

lines(x,ffrech,type='l',lwd=2,col='red')
lines(x,fweib,type='l',lwd=2,col='green')

legend("topright",
       legend=c(TeX(r'(Gumbel(\mu=0,\sigma=1)'),
                TeX(r'(Frechet(\mu=0,\sigma=1,\xi=1)'),
                TeX(r'(Weibull(\sigma=1,\xi=2)')),
       col=c("blue","red","green"),
       lwd=c(2,2,2),cex=1)
```

[image]

Is there a way to correct this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what the problem is, but I couldn't get your latex strings to parse at all. In any case, if you write them directly as R expressions, your problem resolves:

```r
plot(x,fgumb, type = 'l' ,lwd = 2, col = 'blue', ylim = c(0, maxes), ylab = "f(x)")

lines(x, ffrech, type = 'l', lwd = 2, col = 'red')
lines(x, fweib, type = 'l', lwd = 2, col = 'green')

legend("topright",
       legend = c(expression(paste('Gumbel(', mu==0~','~sigma==1, ')')),
                  expression(paste('Frechet(', mu==0~','~sigma==1, ',', xi==1, ')')),
                  expression(paste('Weibull(', sigma==1~','~xi==2, ')'))),
       col = c("blue", "red", "green"),
       lwd = c(2, 2, 2), cex = 1)
```

[image]